# Displaying Natbib generated bibliography in the form: Surname, Name, Title, Publisher, Year

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I have been using the natbib package for a couple of years and I am rather satisfied; however, I have a problem that Google search hasn't solved, nor seems it already answered here...
I would like the bibliography generated by natbib to be displayed in the form:
Surname, Name, Title, Publisher, Year.
For example, the entry:

```
@book{Bec1970,
 address              = {Paris},
 author               = {Bec, Pierre},
 publisher            = {A. \& J. Picard},
 title                = {Manuel pratique de philologie romane},
 year                 = {1970},
 }
```

produces:
Pierre Bec. Manuel pratique de philologie romane. A. & J. Picard, Paris, 1970.

I would like that it be displayed:
Bec, Pierre. Manuel pratique de philologie romane. A. & J. Picard, Paris, 1970.
instead.

I use:

```
\documentclass[reqno, psamsfonts, draft, titlepage, twoside]{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}
\usepackage{ipa}
\usepackage{xyling1}
\usepackage{dashrule}
\makeatother
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{papersize={170mm,240mm},total={124mm,185mm}}
\usepackage[a4,cam,center]{crop}
```

in the preamble, and

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{bibliography}
```

just before

```
\end{document}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Your code is incomplete. And please use *code sample* syntax (the buttom with `101010`) to show your code.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate your own bst (bibtex style file) using Custombib.

http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/